# Do Swiss professors have the highest gross income in the world?

Tags: professorship

- [Countries With The Highest Professor Salaries In The World](https://naibuzz.com/10-countries-with-the-highest-professor-salaries-in-the-world/)

This article says that Switzerland is the country where university professors are paid the highest salary.

However, my question is, if we take this answer

- [How do university professors earn money beyond their salary?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/173281/100406)

into account,

do Swiss professors have the highest gross income in the world?

If not, which country is that?

Comment: I know that this is not the answer but the question which you should probably also ask yourself is what is the purchasing power and quality of life in that country. Some areas in Switzerland, like Curych, are extremely expensive.

Comment: Note that in some countries the salary of professors varies widely between individuals. There are professors in the US who make vastly more than this swiss salary but there are also a lot more professors in the US who make considerably less.

Comment: The article you cite does not look reliable. I don't believe they looked at all countries in the world, nore took care of purchasing power, nore look at variability in the saleries, nore look at different income sources, etc. That makes sense, doing this right is expensive and articles like this do not generate the kind of income to justify that kind of expense. On the other hand, doing this kind of article (the 10 most ...) quick and dirty is easy and cheap, but does generate "clicks". So you see a lot of articles of this type, that are of very low quality.

Comment: Plus, of course, what people earn *beyond their salary* (which may be transparent, e.g., in Germany), is very much up to the professor themselves. So unless you have access to tax records for all professors all over the world, the question is unanswerable.

Comment: Seems like a very clear, even empirical, legitimate question: what's the country with the highest average salary for professors? Votes to re-open

Comment: It is not about the highest average salary as the OP explicitly wanted "money earned beyond their salary" to be included.